# How canI manually reload context in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'd like to manually reload, or "hot deploy", the context of my project through Eclipse. I'm aware of how to do it through Tomcat's `manager/html` console, but I have to stop my server running Eclipse, run Tomcat's startup.bat, enter in the credentials, etc. etc., which is very time consuming.

Could this be done in Eclipse somehow?

Some things tI've tried

- Restarting the server doesn't reload the context
- Building the project *only sometimes* reloads the context
- Tomcat's `manager/html` process is time consuming

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was disabling the Javascript Validator built into Eclipse. I'm working with Ext JS, which is mostly .js files, and it's a fairly large framework. The validator is what was dragging my application to the ground and taking forever. Hope this helps anyone who's experiencing a considerable lag in performance on their eclipse prject.